# live555 sample test program not playable by VLC

Tags: vlc, live555

I am currently examining the sample open source code of LIVE555 streaming media to test video streaming.
I have compiled successfully on one Ubuntu 16.04 system in Virtual machine, ran the test program ./testH264VideoStreamer without any error message. In the console, the program is running as:

```
./testH264VideoStreamer
Play this stream using the URL "rtsp://172.18.15.20:8554/testStream"
Beginning streaming...
Beginning to read from file...
...done reading from file
Beginning to read from file...
...done reading from file
Beginning to read from file...
```

However, on the VLC player, I cannot view the video. Any help or suggestion is sincerely appreciated.

[VLC player setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9898.png)
[image]

[VLC streaming](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8pQ6.png)
[image]

Note:

1. I have not made any changes to the downloaded source code yet.
2. Media file "test.264" is playable if directly played on VLC player, the file is placed in ./live/testProgs and renamed to "test.264"
3. Unlike if VLC could not detect the IP or files, there is no error message popped out on either VLC side or console side. It seems like it just cannot decode the video correctly
4. The Virtual machine and VLC player is on the same computer. Not sure if this will affect the performance. The IP of VM ubuntu is a static IP.

Answer (score 0):

This is because VLC doesnot detect the demuxer to use.

Using test program testH264VideoStreamer send an elementary stream of H264 frames, you need to say to VLC to use H264 demuxer instead of using automatic detection.

This could be done in different ways :

- adding --demux h264 in the command line (for instance `vlc --demux h264 rtsp://172.18.15.20:8554/testStream`)
- adding /h264 to the url (using `rtsp/h264://172.18.15.20:8554/testStream`)
- selecting H264 demuxer in "Preferences" -> "Input / Codecs" -> "Demuxers"

Comment: Hi mpromonet, thanks a lot for replying! Actually I did notice this and already set to H264 video demuxer in preferences before testing, so unlikely this is the root cause. However, while I tried to connect to the streamer from a different PC by VLC, it works! So i guess there is just some port conflict between VM and windows on the same machine. Again, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Solved by accessing from a different computer in the same network, possible due to conflict of VM ports and Windows VLC in same physical machine. For similar problem faced by others, should always try mpromonet's way if haven't do so.